# custom drop down list in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I am trying to create a kind of custom drop down which will have a method name from which it will get all of its element, and before knockout model binding it should wait for the list to be populated from the method given and then start its default behaviour.

so far I am successful on populating data from a given method. but the problem is how can I tell knockout binding to wait till my init method complete its asynch working.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.serviceMethod = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var serviceName, optionsValue, optionsText, value, optionsCaption, isCompleted;

        if (element.nodeName == 'SELECT') {                
            optionsValue = allBindings().optionsValue || 'value';
            optionsText = allBindings().optionsText || 'text';                
            serviceName = valueAccessor();               

            var l = $(element);
            serviceName.apply().done(function (results) {
                l.empty();
                $.each(results.List, function (j, result) {
                    l.append($("<option />").val(result[optionsValue] || '').text(result[optionsText] || ''));
                })                    
            });
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        //what to do now in order to let knockout wait for list to be populated
    }
 }
```

my binding is

```
<select name="state" data-bind="serviceMethod:registrationService.getAllStates,value: model.state" id="ddlState"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the input element until data is available, An [Extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) can do this.

The markup:

```
<select data-bind="serviceMethod:getOptions, options: options, enable:options.enable></select>
```

The viewmodel:

```
function viewModel(){
    this.options=ko.observableArray().extend( { enabled:false});       
}
```

The binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.serviceMethod = {
     init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var getOptionsFunction=valueAccessor();
        // deferred implemented as a callback
        getOptionsFunction(function(r){
           allBindings().options(r);               
           // call extender observable to enable the input
           allBindings().options.enabled(true); 
        } );
    },
    update:function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    }
```

The extender:

```
ko.extenders.enabled = function(target, option) {
    target.enabled=ko.observable(option);
    return target;
};
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Cd76/)

**note**: I would move the logic to the view model, in our project we made mistakes to put too much coding in binding handlers that should go to viewModels.

Comment: thank you for your reply, your solution is good but its like enable drop down list but what I need is to select the option given from server. I am using mapping plugin. please have a look at both fiddles, first one is what I need to do but instead selecting the value in deferred response this value is given from server in JSON format which is used to get view Model from mapping plugin. http://jsfiddle.net/u578D/1/    http://jsfiddle.net/R26pr/1/

Comment: Made a small change to lazy-initialise the observable using a second extender.  see  http://jsfiddle.net/R26pr/2/

Comment: this is a good way to handle the situation, I achieved it by extending ajax based variable with an observable called 'populated' and making it true in onDemandObservable whenever I receive ajax response from server and in my viewModel I used a computed observable for all ajax based observables to be populated and returned a deferred object and on its promise I applied bindings in my module boot strap file.

Answer (score 1):

That is how I achieved it, first I extended knockout like

```
ko.extenders.asyncList = function (target, option) {

    var _callbackF = [];
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function () {

            if (!target.populated()) {
                option.apply().done(_addintoList);
            } 
            return target;
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });

    target.populated = ko.observable(false);
    target.refresh = function () {
        target.populated(false);
    }    
    var _addintoList = function (aData) {

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(aData.List, function (item) {
            target.push(item);
        });

        if (_callbackF != undefined) {
            $.each(_callbackF, function (_f) {
                _f.apply();
            });
            _callback = undefined;
        }
        target.populated(true);
    }
    return result();
}
```

then view model using this extension like

```
staticData: function () {
    var self = this;
    var def = $.Deferred();
    self.allStates = ko.observableArray().extend({ asyncList: registrationService.getAllStates });
    self.hearUsAll = ko.observableArray().extend({ asyncList: registrationService.getAllSources });;
    self.populated = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            if (this.allStates.populated() && this.hearUsAll.populated()) {
                return def.resolve(true);
            }
            return def;
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    }, this);
```

then my main function uses it like

```
this.staticData.populated().done(
        function (d) {
            ko.applyBindings({ model: self.dataModel, staticData: self.staticData, view: self.viewModel })
        });
```

Comment: I am sharing this if experts can help me finding better solution than this